# How can a Flask app running on supervisord open an SSH tunnel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, supervisord, ssh-tunnel

**Note**: I included Flask in the question, but I doubt it has anything to do with Flask and all to do with `supervisord` and `sshtunnel`.

Basically, I'm trying to open an SSH tunnel to connect to a database and perform some commands programatically. This always happens on a worker `Thread` opened with the `threading` library. This works fine by directly invoking Gunicorn or by running the script directly. This is the function:

```py
def _get_ssh_server(client):
    """Open an SSH tunnel forwarder and return it."""

    return sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (os.environ['SSH_HOSTNAME'], int(os.environ['SSH_PORT'])),
        ssh_username=os.environ['SSH_USERNAME'],
        ssh_pkey=os.environ['SSH_PKEY'],
        remote_bind_address=(
            os.environ['REMOTE_BIND_ADDRESS'], 3306),
        local_bind_address=("localhost", int(
            os.environ['LOCAL_BIND_PORT']))
    )
```

Obviously those environment variables exist and are correct. When I run locally and by directly calling Gunicorn (even on the remote server), things work fine.

When I run `sudo service supervisord restart` and observe the logs, I see:

```
ValueError: No password or public key available!
```

Here's the command part of the `supervisord` app `.ini`.

```
command=/usr/local/bin/pipenv run gunicorn -w 3 manage:app
```

Research tells me that it's something to do with the way `supervisord` works with `ssh-agent`. On both `root` and the user I am working with, the private key exists in `~/.ssh` in `id_rsa` with correct permissions. Running Gunicorn directly on both works, isolating the problem to `supervisord`.

I could probably get this to work using `screen` or similar, but that is not a preferred solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I was able to get it to fail by, as root, deleting the `/home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa` file, killing the SSH agent, and restarting it. I got it to work again by running `ssh-add`. Running with `supervisord` still does not work.

If the SSH agent `supervisor` uses is the same as the one `root` uses, why doesn't it work?

Comment: system may have special "users" to run services not as root. And these users may not have your settings nor home folder with `~/.ssh`

Comment: Previously, I added `user=root` to the `.ini` config file for `supervisord`. It's not there any more as the same issue persisted. Just in case, this time around I added a log statement to find the running user, and it's `root`. `/root/.ssh/id_rsa` is the correct key file.

Comment: Have you dumped the ENV vars to ensure they are present and scoped to your user? How about hard coding in the direct path to your key to debug that... Also, I'd suggest opening the proxy tunnel outside of python/your-app-server (bash) or if you still want to go python, I'd separate it as a init.d/systemctl service to ensure the tunnel is opening and not closing out (not 100% if the tunnel would persist in a python thread)

Comment: @John Yeah, environment variables are correct and the path definitely exists to the SSH key (does not use `$HOME` nor `~/`). I think separating the two is a good idea, though. What I was concerned about at the start was problems with the tunnel dying when trying to run a database query without the ability to relaunch. For every single query, I used a context manager to open a new tunnel and DB connection so closing out would be less of a problem, but now I have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've managed to fix it myself. I'm not 100% sure why it didn't work before, but I have an alternative solution still using the same tools.

`sshtunnel`'s documentation stated that you could either use a file path or a `paramiko` `RSAKey` in place of `ssh_pkey`. I've been using a `str` file path this entire time, so I tried the other way.

First thing I did was change the private key's format from OpenSSH to RSA:

```sh
ssh-keygen -p -m PEM -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Next up, I changed the block of code that loads in the SSH key to:

```py
import paramiko

# ...

def _get_ssh_server(client):
    """Open an SSH tunnel forwarder and return it."""

    return sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (os.environ['SSH_HOSTNAME'], int(os.environ['SSH_PORT'])),
        ssh_username=os.environ['SSH_USERNAME'],
        ssh_pkey=paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(os.environ['SSH_PKEY']),
        remote_bind_address=(os.environ['REMOTE_BIND_ADDRESS'], 3306),
        local_bind_address=("localhost", int(os.environ['LOCAL_BIND_PORT'])),
        allow_agent=False,
    )
```

Everything now works as expected.